# joshcam php $db->has function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working with this [Mysqli](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/) php Class. 
After i've read the documentation and after various attempts, i'm locked on this simply login script i'm writing. 
If i try to login with some login detail that are not present in the db, it redirect me to the user page. I don't now how to fix this issue for now, because this problem will persist also if i try with the `$db->has()` function. As shown into the class documentation this function is supposed to check into the db to verify if a requested element is present, but the `$db->has()` give me always the wrong username or password error, also if credentials are correct and present in the database.

```
//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

**NB:** This is a wrong way to check for password hashes. Try `print_r($hash);` you will notice that the generated hash from the user password input will never not match the one stored into the db.

```
// check that the hashed password match and query the db.
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$db->where("username", $user);
$db->where("password", password_verify($password, $hash));
$db->get('members');
if($db->has('members')){
$success[] = "You are now logged in";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header('refresh:5; url=dashboard.php');
} else {
$error[] = "Wrong username or password";
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've made a test page and it seems to work fine. As suggested in a comment, I have first queried the database to verify if the username exist, then after the query is executed,I've created two variables to check if the password and the username are correct.

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){

$cols = Array ("username","password");
$db->where('username', $_POST['username']);
//execute the query
$results = $db->get("members", null, $cols);
// fetch the results and verify credentials for the login
if(!empty($results)){
foreach($results as $results){
$username = $results['username'];
$hashPwd = $results['password'];
}
$verifyPwd = password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashPwd);
if($_POST['username'] == $username and $verifyPwd == TRUE){
echo 'success';
#this print is used inly to verify if the query work print_r($results); 
}
}else {
#this print is only to verify if the query work print_r($results);
echo 'error';
} 
}
```

**NB:**
As reported in the comments, the first version of the working code i've posted in the edit, was potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

I've added some security functions to make the script a little bit safer, see the code below. Every suggestion to improve security will be appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

require('includes/MysqliDb.php');

$db = new MysqliDb ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_recordz');

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//sanitize user input
$query = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

$fields = array('username', 'password');
foreach($fields as $fieldname){
if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
$error[] = 'Empty '.$fieldname.'<br/>'; 
}
}

if(!$error) {
$cols = Array ("email","username","password");
$db->escape($query);
```

**NB:** `$db->escape()` function is a class wrapper of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. I've used `$db->where()` and `$db->orWhere()` to check the db for the username or email, this give the user the possibility to use both for login. If you use only the `$db->where()`, it will not work.

```
$db->where('username', $query);
$db->orWhere('email', $query);
$results = $db->get("members", null, $cols);
if(!empty($results)){
foreach($results as $results){
$username = $results['username'];
$usermail = $results['email'];
$hashPwd = $results['password'];
}
```

**NB:** This is how i check for the password, the correct way. From the results array i've assigned the `$hashPwd` variable to the hashed password stored into the database, then i've used the `password_verify()` to match the hash and check if the inserted password is correct. The `password_hash()` is not needed for login scope.

```
$verifyPwd = password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashPwd);

if($query == $username and $verifyPwd == TRUE){
$success[] = 'Login Success';
     print_r($results);
}

elseif($query == $usermail and $verifyPwd == TRUE){
$success[] = 'Login Success';
     print_r($results);
}else {
$error[] = 'Wrong username or email address';
     print_r($results);
}

}else {
$error[] = 'Wrong username and/or password';
     print_r($results);
}

}
}
ob_end_flush();

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: `password_verify` returns a boolean, so perhaps you should be passing in $hash instead.

Comment: @NigelRen I've tried to run the code also without the `password_verify()` and `password_hash()` function, butt the problem persist. Correct credentials are not verified and the user/password error message is displayed.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fetch the user based purely on the username, then use password_verify to check the value from the record with the one the use has entered.

Comment: @NigelRen so you suggest to write two separate query for the login?

Comment: No - query using just the user name, then once you have found a matching record, use password_verify to check the password the user has entered against what you have on this record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
//process login form if submitted 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$user = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
//check that the hashed password match
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
//query the database for result 
$db->where("username", $user); 
$db->where("password", password_verify($password, $hash)); 
$getuser = $db->getOne('members');
if(!empty($getuser)) {
$success[] = "You are now logged in";
 $_SESSION['username'] =$user['username']; 
header('refresh:5; url=dashboard.php'); }
else { $error[] = "Wrong username or password"; }
```

Don't mind my typos am using my phone

Comment: I've tried your code, but it don't work, it always say wrong username or password. Maybe i need to rewrite the entire query?

Comment: What is password hash function and password verify function

Comment: `password_hash()` is to encrypt the password inserted from the user and `password_verify()` is used to verify if the hashed password is the same stored into the db. In this case i think that i can remove both functions.

Comment: I think you can leave the password hash but you need to remove the password verify.

Comment: I don't know if `password_hash` can be useful in this case. I need only to login the users.

Comment: I think it's useful to match the one in db

Comment: The problem for now is not the hash but is to make the code working correctly. It seems like the db is not checked or something similar. I'm new to this php class i've used.

Comment: Pm me if you need more help

Comment: This morning i've tried to select from the db for username and password of an user that i've created without hash the password. In this case, i can see with the `print_r()` function that the returned Array of results can find the username and the password from db with the `$db->get()` function. So i've decided to try removing from the query the password field and the array return to me all the three test user i've created with the username and password.. Is it possible that the problem is because the password are hashed?

Comment: If the hashed password in the db match the hash of the post password i think it won't be a problem

Comment: See the code i've posted in the edit.To solve the issue of hash checking, I've first queried the database to verify if the inputted username is present, then with the results array, i'veused the `password_verify()` to check if the inputted password match the one stored in the db. The funny things is that, if the passwords aren't hashed the `$db->where()` function of the class, works fine if i pass the `$_POST['password']` variable.

Comment: Since you said it's working fyn now, just want you to know that your code is prone to sql injection